# Filtro dinamico usando el operador in con regex SQL

Tags: sql, regex, plsql

Como puedo usar el resultado de un query dentro del operador in, lo he intentado y no me retorna resultados de manera dinamica, pero si lo hago manual y me retorna datos.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (isn) AS
SELECT 'A8176,A8605,A4460' FROM DUAL;


WITH   
        DATA_COD AS (
            SELECT 'A8176' COD, '1' IND FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'A8605' COD, '2' IND FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'A4460' COD, '3' IND FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'A8178' COD, '4' IND FROM DUAL
        )
    SELECT *
    FROM DATA_COD
    WHERE DATA_COD.COD IN (
        SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(isn,
            '([A-Za-z0-9]+)',
            '''\1''',
            1,
            0,
            'c'
        ) OBD
        FROM table_name
    );
```

*Resultado: No rows returned*
[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Gp8JXToF)

Manual:

```
WITH   
    DATA_COD AS (
        SELECT 'A8176' COD, '1' IND FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 'A8605' COD, '2' IND FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 'A4460' COD, '3' IND FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 'A8178' COD, '4' IND FROM DUAL
    )
SELECT *
FROM DATA_COD
WHERE DATA_COD.COD IN ('A8176','A8605','A4460')
;
```

*Resultado:*
[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZIv8W4Sv)

Comment: No entiendo, que es lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: @Yussef Tengo dos tablas una la cual tiene los codigos en una sola columna, estan separados por coma, requeiro hacer la busqueda mediante un in dentro de la tabla DATA_COD en la columna cod, uso el regex para adicionarle la comilla sencilla, pero no me retorna resultados

Comment: @Yussef y alo edite para ver si logro dar un poco mas de contexto

Comment: Esto es lo que quieres??? : `WHERE DATA_COD.COD IN (select regexp_substr(isn,'[^,]+', 1, level) as C from table_name connect by regexp_substr(isn, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)`